# Why does each iteration in this loop take a shorter time when there are more iterations?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop

NOTE: The libraries used in this code can be found [here](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/). The classes/functions used here are pretty self explanatory though.

This brute force algorithm counts all the triplets in the given input that sum to 0:

```
    public static int count(int[] a) {
        int n = a.length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                    if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

When I test it from `i = 250` to `16000`, incrementing `i` by `250` at each iteration:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Stopwatch;

public class DoublingTest {
    public static double timeTrial(int N) {
        int MAX = 1000000;
        int[] a = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = StdRandom.uniform(-MAX, MAX);
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        int cnt = ThreeSum.count(a);
        return timer.elapsedTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 250; i <= 16000; i += 250) {
            double time = timeTrial(i);
            total += time;
            StdOut.printf("%7d %5.2f", i, time);;
            StdOut.printf("Total time = %5.2f\n", total);
        }
    }
}
```

i = 4000 takes 12.91s:

```
    250  0.03
Total time =  0.03
    500  0.10
Total time =  0.13
    750  0.43
Total time =  0.56
   1000  0.95
Total time =  1.51
   1250  1.80
Total time =  3.31
   1500  3.12
Total time =  6.44
   1750  1.11
Total time =  7.55
   2000  1.65
Total time =  9.20
   2250  2.35
Total time = 11.54
   2500  3.19
Total time = 14.74
   2750  4.26
Total time = 18.99
   3000  5.51
Total time = 24.50
   3250  6.99
Total time = 31.50
   3500  8.73
Total time = 40.23
   3750 10.66
Total time = 50.88
   4000 12.91
Total time = 63.80
```

But when I double `i` at each iteration:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Stopwatch;

public class DoublingTest {
    public static double timeTrial(int N) {
        int MAX = 1000000;
        int[] a = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = StdRandom.uniform(-MAX, MAX);
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        int cnt = ThreeSum.count(a);
        return timer.elapsedTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 250; i <= 16000; i *= 2) {
            double time = timeTrial(i);
            total += time;
            StdOut.printf("%7d %5.2f", i, time);
            StdOut.printf("Total time = %5.2f\n", total);
        }
    }
}
```

i = 4000 takes significantly longer (59.22s):

```
    250  0.04
Total time =  0.04
    500  0.12
Total time =  0.16
   1000  0.96
Total time =  1.11
   2000  7.38
Total time =  8.50
   4000 59.22
Total time = 67.71
```

Yet, total time is similar in both cases. Why does this happen?

Comment: You're probably observing the *JIT (just-in-time) compiler* (<- search keyword to find out more) in action. You can try the `-Xint` command line option, which disables it. That should make the results noticeably slower, but perfectly linear.

Comment: What about memory and CPU in your machine? When you add large data you get much memory for heap. Check memory and JVM actual state

Comment: @teapot418 How do I re-enable JIT?

Comment: It's enabled by default. If you don't put the option to disable, it will be enabled.

Comment: Consider replacing the multiplication with addition in the for-loop increment clause - integer addition is faster than integer multiplication.   Interestingly, this is not always true with floating point addition versus floating point multiplication.

Comment: You have to run methods several times before JIT kicks in. So whenever you time something tinme it several times (in the same JVM-run) and wait until values have stabilized. Also GarbageCollection might make some measurements useless (also therefore you need to measure the same test several times).